# Fazer uma função que mostra se o número é inteiro ou não

Tags: javascript, funções

Preciso fazer uma função que retorne: é inteiro ou não é inteiro.

Comment: você já tentou fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, eu não tenho nenhuma lógica em mente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pose usar `parseInt` com `radix 10` (decimal):

```js
function isInt(n){
   return n === parseInt(n, 10);
}

console.log( isInt(1) ); // retorna true
console.log( isInt(1.5) ); // retorna false
console.log( isInt(1.0) ); // retorna true
console.log( isInt(10/5) ); // retorna true
console.log( isInt(10/4) ); // retorna false
```

Note que o operador `===` irá verificar se o valor é igual no valor e no tipo.

Se o tipo for indiferente (número ou string), pode usar `==`:

```js
function isInt(n){
   return n == parseInt(n, 10);
}

// strings
console.log( isInt('1') ); // retorna true
console.log( isInt('1.5') ); // retorna false
console.log( isInt('1.0') ); // retorna true

// números
console.log( isInt(1) ); // retorna true
console.log( isInt(1.5) ); // retorna false
console.log( isInt(1.0) ); // retorna true
```

> Observe que o método `Number.isInteger` não é suportado no Internet
>   Explorer.

Answer (score 7):

Basicamente utilize `Number.isInteger`, exemplo:

```js
// Returns true
console.log(Number.isInteger(100));
console.log(Number.isInteger(-100));

// Returns false
console.log(Number.isInteger(Number.NaN));
console.log(Number.isInteger(Infinity));
console.log(Number.isInteger(100 / 3));
console.log(Number.isInteger("100"));
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Função Number.isInteger (Número) (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn858236(v=vs.94).aspx)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A melhor solucaco seria (compativel com todos os navegadores)

```
function isInteger(numero) {
  return (numero ^ 0) === numero && typeof(numero) == "number";
}
```

Exemplo:

```
 isInteger(2)
 true
 isInteger(1.5)
 false
```